# Oracle Apex Chart - Reset zoom level when refresh

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex, apexcharts

I've got a multi series Orcale Apex line chart. When loading in data, everything looks fine and the data is shown corresponding to the timestamp from the source DB table (X-axis = timeaxis). Now, when I zoom in to a particular date and load in new data in which this very date doesn't exist, my chart shows the new data with the zoomed-in date as starting point instead of using the oldest date found in the new data. In the overview, everything works just fine. Is there a way to reset the zoom to full extend when refreshing the chart?

To illustrate the problem:

[Load in data & zoom to starting date 9th of may 2020](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UPYB.jpg)

[Load in new data with starting date of 12th of april 2020 - zoom gets stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUpm1.jpg)

Comment: What version of APEX are you using?

Comment: I'm using 19.1.0.00.15.

Comment: It could be an issue with Oracle JET that is packaged with your version of APEX. Have you tried reproducing it on apex.oracle.com where the latest version of APEX can be tested?

Comment: @EJEgyed Well, yes, I guess that could be it. I'm just wondering why I wasn't able to find other people with the same problem. I guess it is an rather ordinary use case. As soon as I've got time to do so, I'm going to try as suggested.

Comment: Didn't come up with a real solution, but took another route with a workaround: I'm generating the link via javascript location.assign( ) method dynamically and fill in the user's choices in the selection lists. This way, everything works fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Little late but i got the same problem.
The problem is related to the viewport because it refresh the and set the min and max values of the xAxis, but the min and max value of the viewport still set. So you need to unset the viewport to render it ok.

```
$("#Jobs_jet").ojChart("option","xAxis.viewportMax",null);
$("#Jobs_jet").ojChart("option","xAxis.viewportMin",null);
```