# Oracle Apex - Link to same page with values from selection lists

Tags: javascript, dynamic, hyperlink, oracle-apex

I'm trying to build up a link that includes three values from the choices of selection lists. It should point to the same page and reload it (page 11) while transferring the said values. By this, a chart is loaded which gets its data via pl sql query which is completed with the variables from the link. This works when having the link pointing to page 11 on another page (page 3). The values here are coming from an interactive report and the link ist generated via the link builder. When trying to reload the same page, it doesn't get the values from the choices of the selection lists. I guess it reads the values when the page is loaded and not dynamically, therefore they always stay empty. Is there an easy solution for this (perhaps using javascript)?

This is how the working link from Page3 to Page11 looks like:

`/apex/f?p=&APP_ID.:11:'||:APP_SESSION||'::NO::CLASS,OBJECT,ATTRIBUTE:'||:P3_CLASS||','||:P3_OBJECT||','||:P3_ATTRIBUTE||'`

Answer (score -1):

It should be as simple as creating a button with action "Submit Page". This will submit the page and pick up the selected values.

Comment: When doing so, I'm running into this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68831874/oracle-apex-chart-reset-zoom-level-when-refresh (haven't found a solution either the problem's cause yet )

Comment: Didn't come up with a real solution, but took another route with a workaround: I'm generating the link via javascript location.assign( ) method dynamically and fill in the user's choices in the selection lists. This way, everything works fine now.